# A fireplace is at the base of a chimney and is usually made of "stone(s) or brick(s)"

Tags: grammar

How come it's not "made of stones or bricks" in the following sentence? Thank you!

[A fireplace is at the base of a chimney and is usually made of stone or brick](https://grammarist.com/usage/fireplace-vs-hearth/).

Comment: It's being used as the name of the material, not the individual building blocks.

Comment: @LukeSawczak  That should probably be an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use those terms in reference to the material, in which case they're mass nouns.

> I'm not [made of stone](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/be-made-of-stone)!

> This is a brick building. It won't go up in flames as fast as a wooden frame.

You can also use them (as you expected) in reference to individual chunks of that material: stones or bricks.

Comment: Thank you all for your assistance and help!